# Trans tag in django template does not function as it should

Tags: django, localization, translation

I perhaps miss the entire logic of the {% trans %} tag, but:

I have a view where I pass a certain variable `myvar`:

```
class MyView(TemplateView):
    def get_context_data(self):
        return {'myvar':'something to translate'}
```

Note that it is not wrapped in `ugettext` or `ugettext_lazy` (yet).

Then my understanding was that if I use `myvar` on a template in `trans` tag it will be marked for translation when I use `django-admin makemessages` command:

```
{% load otree  i18n %}
<h1>{% trans myvar %}</h1>
```

But that does not happen. However if I adjust my view like that:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class MyView(TemplateView):
    def get_context_data(self):
        return {'myvar':_('something to translate')}
```

then of course it is added to messages for translation after a corresponding command is run.

But then I can use this translated `myvar` variable without any {% trans %} tags, so what's the point of it at all?

Comment: The use of `{% trans ''}` is for strings inside the html which you are planning to keep there. So for example you have a login button thats in an anchor tag inside your html and would like to translate them, then you would add a trans tag to mark it for translation like `{% trans "Login" %}`

Comment: no. In official django documentation (here) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/translation/#trans-template-tag
they cite {% trans myvar %} as an example

Comment: Read a little further "In case a template var (myvar above) is passed to the tag, the tag will first resolve such variable to a string at run-time and then look up that string in the message catalogs.". The string is resolved, then looked up. this var wont be marked for translation as is when marked in the template only, it must be marked in the source first and translated then the template tag can pick it up.

Comment: so if it is already marked for translation earlier (like in views.py for instance), it does not make any sense to put it into {% trans %} tag, right? because it will be translated anyway, so we can just use it directly like {{ myvar }} at the template.

Comment: I find a it a good way to aid with translations. So for example, of I have a status flag of `SUCCESS` and `FAILURE` defined somewhere and passed to some view, and I use the same words in other views being passed to other templates, in that case, you dont need to mark that string in all your views to be translated, and when you send it to your template along with trans tag, it will resolve it automatically from you trans files.

Comment: ah! Now I see: in other 'views' we can use this text directly without wrapping it into `ugettext`, and just use it in {% trans %} tag to be translated. Thanks a lot! Now I got it